# Need one table count for all record and status count for activate and deactivate separately (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need one table count for all record and status count for activate and deactivate separately.  This is what I have so far.  Can anyone help?

```sql
 SELECT id COUNT(*),(SELECT id COUNT(*),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
 beauty_users WHERE status = Deactivate)AS TOT FROM beauty_users WHERE
 status = Activate) AS TOT FROM beauty_users
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find total count, count of rows with activate status and count of rows with Deactivate status.

If so, try this:

```
select
    count(*) count_all,
    count(case when status = 'Activate' then 1 end) Activated,
    count(case when status = 'Deactivate' then 1 end) Deactivated
from beauty_users
```